# What is the best way to test my predictions if the true values are not included in the test set?

Tags: linear-model, prediction, train

What is the best way to test my predictions if the true values are not included in the test set?

Comment: Is this question perhaps more philosophical than statistical? How does one grade a test when one does not know the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use that test set. If it doesn't have values of the dependent variable, it's not useful for model validation. Use cross-validation or a new train–test split in your training data instead.